# Button Issue in custom tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

So, I'm making a weather app in python using custom Tkinter library. And there's a little in ctk which shows "CTKButton" in the actual button when I try use CTkimage.

Note that this only happens when I change the width to the button. What I think is that it's a bug with the library. And I don't want it to be just a image. I want it to be a functional button.

**The button looks like this:**
[image: img]

**Here's the code:**

```
# Importing the libraries
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import PhotoImage
import requests
import subprocess
from PIL import Image

# Open Weather API Key
api_key = "382c3e7cbd2cf169915da81a88eca8c2"

def get_weather():
    city = city_entry.get()
    if not city:
        weather_label.config(text="Please enter a city")
        description_label.config(text="")
        temperature_label.config(text="")
        humidity_label.config(text="")
        return

    url = f"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&appid={api_key}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    weather_data = response.json()

    if weather_data["cod"] != "404":
        main_weather = weather_data["weather"][0]["main"]
        description = weather_data["weather"][0]["description"]
        temperature = weather_data["main"]["temp"] - 273.15  # fix this soon
        humidity = weather_data["main"]["humidity"]

        weather_label.configure(text=f"Weather: {main_weather}")
        description_label.configure(text=f"Description: {description}")
        temperature_label.configure(text=f"Temperature: {temperature:.1f}°C")
        humidity_label.configure(text=f"Humidity: {humidity}%")
    else:
        weather_label.configure(text="City not found")
        description_label.configure(text="")
        temperature_label.configure(text="")
        humidity_label.configure(text="")

def open_credits_script():
    subprocess.run(["python", "credits_script.py"])


# Custom Tkinter Setup

ctk.set_appearance_mode('Dark')
ctk.set_default_color_theme('dark-blue')

# Main Window

root = ctk.CTk()
root.title("Suntrack - A Weather App")
root.geometry('800x600')
root.iconbitmap("image_res/icon.ico")

# Load in images

info_img = ctk.CTkImage(light_image=Image.open("image_res/info.png"))

# Buttons and labels

city_entry = ctk.CTkEntry(root, font=('Helvetica', 20))
city_entry.pack(pady=10)

get_weather_button = ctk.CTkButton(root, text='Search', command=get_weather, width=10)
get_weather_button.place(x=500, y=11)

weather_label = ctk.CTkLabel(root, text="", font=('Helvetica', 20))
weather_label.pack()

description_label = ctk.CTkLabel(root, text="", font=('Helvetica', 20))
description_label.pack()

temperature_label = ctk.CTkLabel(root, text="", font=('Helvetica', 20))
temperature_label.pack()

humidity_label = ctk.CTkLabel(root, text="", font=('Helvetica', 20))
humidity_label.pack()

credits_button = ctk.CTkButton(root, image=info_img, width=4, command=open_credits_script)
credits_button.place(x=600, y=570) # Orginally 720

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is.

Comment: When I run your script, it seems to work fine. I see the image and the text, and clicking on it calls the appropriate function. Are you asking how to remove the "CTkButton" text on the button? Have you tried adding `text=""`?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use a set width for your widget, you should set the `text` parameter value to `None` to get rid of the text, if that's what you're looking to do (please clarify).

```py
credits_button = ctk.CTkButton(root, image=info_img, width=4, text=None, command=open_credits_script)
```

However, I would recommend using an image as the full button and scrapping the `width` value, so you're not relying on a library (also shorter code yay).